# Read characters from serial port in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hello I am using Read() method to read 10 characters say 0123456789 from serial port. Actually the characters are sent by a PIC Micro-controller.

Here is my code:

```
serialPort1.PortName = "com4";
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort1.Open();
char[] result = new char[10];
serialPort1.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
string s = new string(result);
MessageBox.Show(s);
serialPort1.Close();
```

When I run the code, a message box shows up and displays only the first character. "0" alone is displayed in the message box.

Where have i gone wrong ??

Comment: Debug and see what is in your result variable.

Comment: You have to read it first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704329/reading-data-from-serial-port-in-c-sharp

Comment: Your controller only sent one character? (`serialPort1.Read` will return the number of bytes read)

Comment: @AustinSalonen No the controller actually sent 10 characters.

Comment: Are you sending nulls in between?  That would terminate the string.

Comment: How did you prove that 10 characters were sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is not paying attention to the return value of Read().  Which tells you how many bytes were read.

Serial ports are very slow devices, at a typical baudrate setting of 9600 it takes a millisecond to get one byte transferred.  That's an enormous amount of time for a modern processor, it can easily execute several million instructions in a millisecond.  The Read() method returns as soon as *some* bytes are available, you only get all 10 of them if you make your program artificially slow so the driver gets enough time to receive all of them.

A simple fix is to keep calling Read() until you got them all:

```
char[] result = new char[10];
for (int len = 0; len < result.Length; ) {
   len += serialPort1.Read(result, len, result.Length - len);
}
```

Another common solution is to send a unique character to indicate the end of the data.  A line feed ('\n') is a very good choice for that.  Now it becomes much simpler:

```
string result = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

Which now also supports arbitrary response lengths.  Just make sure that the data doesn't also contain a line feed.