# How can I get data in Serialport with a third program?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

There is a program (b) that communicates with an external device (a) through serial port.
I want to know what data a and b exchange.
I tried to open and check the ComPort where A and B are communicating in my program, but...
Of course, the comport already open in b cannot be opened again in my program.
Is there an appropriate solution?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Data from serial port in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704329/reading-data-from-serial-port-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @osfresia Thanks for answer, but no.
The main issue of that question is communication problem between [my program] and [device].
But my issue is how I can get the data (with Com Port) exchanged between the [third program] and [the device] in [my program].

Answer (score 0):

### Sniff serial port programmatically

If you want to use C# (so sniff serial port programmatically) and avoid low level serial port hooking)
The quick and dirty solution is to interpose your software using 2 further COM ports.

`a <=> your C# app <=> b`

You can use some virtual COM port driver - [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) - to emulate further ports, if you need.

### Just sniff data for a while

Install and use a freeware software (there are a lot, just google "serial port software sniffer"). `PortMon` of SysInternal was a great tool for that. But it's no more supported (and I was not able to use in Win10...)

Comment: yes, I use Win10... and thanks for your solution, I will try soon.